# Hiding interface methods in Intellisense in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, interface, intellisense

I have an interface and it has many methods. I should not see these methods in Intellisense in implementing classes. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **[EditorBrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx)** on your methods.

> EditorBrowsableAttribute Specifies that a property or method is viewable in an editor. 
>   EditorBrowsableAttribute is a hint to a designer indicating whether a property or method is to be displayed. You can use this type in a visual designer or text editor to determine what is visible to the user. For example, the IntelliSense engine in Visual Studio uses this attribute to determine whether to show a property or method.

Something like

```
   [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
   public void GetId()
   {
   }
```

Comment: as long as working with code in the same assembly the EditorBrowsable is ignored

Comment: Thanks for the valuable Answer :)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to implement them explicitly.

If your interface is:

```
interface IFoo{
  void DoSomething();
}
```

then you can implement that explicitly in a class like below:

```
class Foo : IFoo {
  void IFoo.DoSomething();
}
```

That being said, you probably wonder consider why you want to do this. An interface is often used to define a contract of what an object of a given type is capable of. Wanting to hide it can be a smell of something go astray in the design process. Of course there's also many valid cases for the use of explicit implementation. E.g. Dictionary has explicit implementations for quite a few of the methods from IEnumerable>. but the hiding should be more the exception than the rule.

If you declare the variable/member of the interface type the methods will show, if you declare the member/variable of the concrete type they will not show. Since you should generally prefere interfaces to concrete classes this again is a hint that you might wanna look at the reason for wanting to hide the methods declared by the interface

Comment: Thanks, this make sense to me... this is actually an interview question, Can you please tell me if there is any other way we can hide the methods of interface in intellisense?

Comment: @Neelima it's a very odd interview question for at least two reasons. 1) there's no perfect answer. Using the attribute only works outside the assembly and explicit implementation is not meant for this. 2) it's an either you know it or you don't question. Those kind of questions don't tell you anything about the profficiency of the interviewee only about his or her memory but nothing about their ability to design,analyse or problem solving in general

Comment: Thanks a lot Rune....I think, the intellisense wont support when we explicitly implementing it. That means when we write a interface name and put a dot, we should not get the method names in intellisene... may be i need to answer, "in explicit implementation, we will not get intellisense support"... :)